# Entering in ui-select a value that is not in the list

Tags: ui-select, angular-ui-select

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/36IRP9J079vjWFIFjRSb?p=preview) I have a ui-select with a list containing names. I need to allow the user to enter a name from the list or a name that is not in the list.

If I try to enter a name not in the list, ui-select automatically repaces that value with the closest in the list.

Is there a way to a value not in the list?

HTML

```
      <ui-select ng-model="ctrl.person.selected" theme="bootstrap">
        <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="item in ctrl.people | filter: $select.search">
          <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
          <small ng-bind-html="item.email | highlight: $select.search"></small>
        </ui-select-choices>
      </ui-select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [tagging](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select) feature of ui-select to achieve what you want. Please see [this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pcC7nyJQo68tiARkJJAl?p=preview) for a demo - if you type "Gary" into the box then tab out, it will populate with "Gary".

To use the tagging feature, you need to specify the attribute `tagging` and `tagging-label` as follows:

```
<ui-select ng-model="ctrl.person.selected" tagging="ctrl.tagTransform" tagging-label="false">
```

Because your model is an array of objects (not strings) then you will need to specify a function which will add the "new" item into the model:

```
vm.tagTransform = function(newTag) {
  var item = {
    name: newTag,
    email: newTag+'@email.com',
    age: 'unknown',
    country: 'unknown'
  };
  return item;
};
```

Please note that the age and country have been set to "unknown" as we can't determine what they are by just typing the name in. The email also defaults to "NAME@email.com".

There is also a [bug](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/983) with ui-select where `tagging-label` needs to be set to `false` (for tagging to work in single select mode). This unfortunately means that you can't specify a tagging-label function to appear in the dropdown when you are typing (this does work in multiple select mode though).